# How to get row index of a mat table, through its input field event passing?

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

My table has one input column which is type = numeric. When I passed it's value for its .ts file I have used both keyup and change events. This includes in the one of column. Now i need to pass the row index through above both events. How can I do it?

Contribution Percentage 
                        
                          
                          
                            
                            %

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use index in row like this

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element let i= index"> <input (keyup)=function(i)></td>
  </ng-container>
```

you can also read about trackBy